# How can I save the MySQL query output to file on a Windows machine?

Tags: mysql, windows, files

Let's say I want to save the whole list of the collations supported by MySQL into file.
How can I save the result of the `show collation` into `.txt` file?
The OS I'm using is Windows. I tried something like this: `show collation INTO OUTFILE 'c:\aaa.txt';` or `show collation > c:\aaa.txt;` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * 
into outfile 'filepath.txt'
from information_schema.collations;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
C:  mysql -e "select * from information_schema.collations" >collations.txt
```